# For Python Pandas, how can I append to a column value (type list) based on the index date range?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

The data is a dataframe with a single column, namely 'tickers' which is a list of stock symbols.

```
date        tickers

1996-01-02  [AAL, AAMRQ, AAPL, ABI, ABS, ABT, ABX, ACKH, A...
1996-01-03  [AAL, AAMRQ, AAPL, ABI, ABS, ABT, ABX, ACKH, A...
1996-01-04  [AAL, AAMRQ, AAPL, ABI, ABS, ABT, ABX, ACKH, A...
1996-01-10  [AAL, AAMRQ, AAPL, ABI, ABS, ABT, ABX, ACKH, A...
1996-01-11  [AAL, AAMRQ, AAPL, ABI, ABS, ABT, ABX, ACKH, A...
```

If the date is greater than 2018-10-31, I want to append the ticker symbol "Lin" to the list.  I have a solution already, but I doubt is optimal.  Here is what I have:

```
# add LIN after 2018-10-31
def _add_symbol(row, symbol, date):
    if row.name > date:
        row.tickers.append(symbol)
    return row.tickers
df['tickers'] = df.apply(_add_symbol, symbol='LIN', date='2018-10-31', axis=1)
```

I bet there is a one liner using lambda that will do the same thing, but I couldn't figure it out, so I went with what I know to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using apply whenever possible, but appending items to a list in a cell is tricky and I'm not sure of any way to do so without some sort of iteration. That being said, your operation could be optimized slightly by placing the date conditional in an indexer and then applying on the filtered result. This should provide some noticeable increase in speed:

```
df.loc[df['date']>'2018-10-31','tickers'].apply(lambda x: x.append('LIN'))
```

**Edit:**
some quick comparisons on apply vs. columnwise operations.
For this example I just used a simple operation where the values in column 'A' were being incremented by 1. We'll compare the two following methods of achieving the aforementioned result:

```
apply_op = """
df['A']=df.apply(lambda row: row['A']+1,axis=1)
"""
series_op = """
df['A']=df['A']+1
"""
```

First we'll run some speed tests to see how quickly each performs.

```
df:
      A  B  C  D
0     1  2  9  6
1     5  8  1  9
2     6  8  0  1
3     6  1  6  8
4     9  0  1  4
..   .. .. .. ..
995   1  3  8  9
996   1  2  3  3
997   2  2  9  1
998   4  9  2  5
999  10  2  0  3

[1000 rows x 4 columns]

Apply op:
[in]:
df['A']=df.apply(lambda row: row['A']+1,axis=1)
[out]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  9  6
1  5  8  1  9
2  6  8  0  1
3  6  1  6  8
4  9  0  1  4
Average execution time:0.0226791306 ms

Series op:
[in]:
df['A']=df['A']+1
[out]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  9  6
1  5  8  1  9
2  6  8  0  1
3  6  1  6  8
4  9  0  1  4
Average execution time:0.0005004938999999986 ms
```

The series operation has ~4000% increase in speed.

Now lets take a look under the hood and see what instructions are compiled for each operation:

```
>>> dis.dis(apply_op)
  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (df)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (apply)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <lambda> at 0x090B56A8, file "<dis>", line 2>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<lambda>')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 (('axis',))
             14 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         2
             16 LOAD_NAME                0 (df)
             18 LOAD_CONST               4 ('A')
             20 STORE_SUBSCR
             22 LOAD_CONST               5 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x090B56A8, file "<dis>", line 2>:
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (row)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')
              4 BINARY_SUBSCR
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(series_op)
  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (df)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ('A')
              4 BINARY_SUBSCR
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (df)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 ('A')
             14 STORE_SUBSCR
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

It's been a while since I've had to write any assembly, but I'll try to quickly explain what we see above. The first output of apply_op shows the subroutine of the apply function that is called for every single row in the df. For each row, the row, column ('A'), and constant (1) must be retrieved to perform the operation.

In the second output for series_op, we can see that the entire column "A" is loaded once as a single constant. This series operation only performs the addition operation twice; once for the the entire array except for the last item, and one last (second) time for the last item of the array.

For a little bit more on array vectorization: (btw, I rarely find a use case for parallelization of dataframes that makes sense.)
[Vectorization and parallelization in Python with Numpy and Pandas](https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2018/02/02/vectorization-and-parallelization-in-python-with-numpy-and-pandas/)

Comment: I showed up late to the party, but my answer is similar. Yours would be slightly faster on the iteration because it only iterates through rows where the condition is met. I'm leaving my answer for posterity, but this is a better answer.

Comment: @Boskosnitch, I tried your solution and it worked.  I love one liners, and I thought there should be one for this.  Question, why should apply() be avoided where possible?  Is it a looping operation?  I was under the impression that it is vectored.  Thanks!

Comment: @fja0568 apply is in fact a loop operation. Honestly this is one of the few instances in which I couldn't think of a solution that didn't involve apply. I'll post some more info in the original answer.

Comment: @fja0568 just added some quick analysis to the original comment.

Comment: @Boskosnitch, Thanks!  This is very helpful.  I will take your advise and try to avoid apply when I can.

Answer (score 0):

This code is computationally more efficient (a little bit) although I don't know if I'd call it better. Your code would work fine and be easier to read.

You can make this even more efficient if you didn't uses lists within the pandas rows. (I could think of a more efficient way to append than using a lambda.)

```
 import numpy as np

 df['tickers'] = np.where(df['date']>pd.to_datetime('2018-10-31'),
                  df['tickers'],
                  df['tickers'].apply(lambda x: x = ['LIN'])
```

Also, be careful about the comparison for the date. I used the same date comparison as the example assuming you know what you are doing, but you are comparing text. For my comparison to work in my sample code, I needed to add `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: the append method modifies the parameter in place, and as a result returns None, so by assigning the value of append to the column you are actually replacing the rows which meet the condition with "None". on top of that, the function does not do what you intended, at least when I ran it.

Comment: You are correct. That was a typo. I edited to fix the error. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No worries. Idk if i messed up the implementation, but when i tried using your example, it appended for columns where the condition was NOT met and returned None for cols where the condition was met. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Correct one again (today is not my day). I mixed up the `np.where` syntax. It's `np.where(condition,value_if_FALSE, value_if_TRUE) The documentation on numpy isn't very clear IMO. Edited answer.

Comment: Lol i have no idea why I didn't notice that either.